# "-if" or "-ive"

Tags: genre

I have to make a report in French but I don't know which of the following sentences is correct.

1. Un test de sécurité applicat**if**
2. Un test de sécurité applicat**ive**

Which one is correct and why ?

Comment: Congruence. Because *applicative* is feminine, and *test* is masculine.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about *sécurité applicative*, not the test.

Comment: Just a question : what does it means ? As a native speaker and an IT guy I don't understand what it is

Comment: Do you mean "application security test"?

In that case, neither expression makes sense. It should be something like "test de sécurité des applications".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That depends on what you want to say.

Either *applicatif* apply to *test* and that would be:

> Un **test** de sécurité **applicatif**

or (more likely) *applicatif* applies to *sécurité* which is feminine so that would be:

> Un test de **sécurité** **applicative**.

Answer (score 5):

Ask the question, what is applicatif(ve) in this situation? A: La sécurité (feminin), you use **applicative**.